# Would using <div> tag for creating a non-independent block in HTML5 be appropriate?

Tags: html

I would like to have a block of text that contains multiple paragraphs inside it to grouped inside the document, so it would be possible to refer to this section via navigation bar and customize via CSS separately from the rest of the document. What tag would be appropriate to use in this for grouping according to HTML5 standards?

I was thinking to use "div" tag for this purpose and put all relevant content inside, but not sure whether it is correct.

I would not be able to use "article" since this section cannot be used separately from this page.

```html
<div>
   <p>test test test</p>
   <p>test test test</p>
   <p>test test test</p>
</div>
```

Would the formatting mentioned above be appropriate in this case?

Comment: Go for it, it's OK. If you don't want to semantically wrap into `<section>` or `<article>` or whatever, go for Divisor.

Comment: There's no correct answer to this question. There are incorrect answers (for instance, `ul` would not be appropriate, since the only valid child of `ul` is `li`). Beyond those constraints, use whatever you feel is appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the functionality does what you need it to do then I don't see why the formatting wouldn't be correct. If you want to refer to a particular section of that div or within that div, I would advise you to either add a class attribute to the div and/or an id attribute or add id attributes to each individual `<p>` tag